# How do I commit with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

There was a problem with my computer and I had to reinstall Windows (7). I installed TortoiseSVN (1.8.11 64 bit) and I see the context menus, but I don't have a commit option in my SVN directory (where the files are), only a few other options. I don't want to update the files from the server but just commit (because only I can commit to this repository). How do I enter my username & password and commit my changes to SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason could be:

- The file hasn't been changed, so there is no commit option available -> or the file is not versioned
- your directory hasn't been added to the SVN
- you haven't made a working copy and you are using some "backup" folders wher you lost the hidden .svn folder -> if so then make a working copy

Comment: Yes, I had to upgrade my working copy and now I can commit. I used a previous version of TortoiseSVN before.